# How to show up a window of an application with VBA ? (Lotus Notes)

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I want to display the Lotus Notes Window when the VBA code is writing the mail in Lotus Notes. I want the Lotus Notes window to be display during all of the operations.

I had tried this code:

```
Sub init_mail()
Dim oSess As Object
Dim ntsServer As String
Dim ntsMailFile As String

Set oSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")    
ntsServer = oSess.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer", True)
ntsMailFile = oSess.GetEnvironmentString("MailFile", True)
Set odb = oSess.GetDatabase(ntsServer, ntsMailFile)
Set Workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Call Workspace.composedocument(, , "Memo")
Set uidoc = Workspace.CURRENTDOCUMENT
uidoc.Document.deliveryreport = "C"
uidoc.Document.Importance = "Haute"
uidoc.Visible = true
```

I thought that Visible could say that Lotus Note stay open and visible.
I assume "Visible" should not be utilize in this way. I've got this error:

```
Execution error '438'
object doesn't support this property or method
```

Comment: if my answer is appropriate, you can set it to accepted :-)

Comment: First of all, the Visible property only means that you *can* see the window if it has the focus. It does not give the window the focus. Secondly, the error message is telling the truth: the OLE server object classes in Lotus Notes do not support the Visible property. If the operation would normally be visible within the Notes client, then it will be visible through OLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good luck with your venture, the OLE/COM Engine for Lotus Notes is antedeluvian and it's a royal pain to debug.

From your code I would hypothesise that you have little experience in LotusScript, you're using programming paradigms that will not work in LotusScript.

Generally I would recommend you first writing code that runs well in the Notes Client, and only when it works, then port it to VBA. Here the integrated Help File is your friend, it's one  of the last remnants of when IBM did decent documentation for the Domino/Notes platform. You'll have to wrap your head around a couple of weird concepts (in this particular case, the difference between front-end and back-end documents), and deal with a plethora of maddening bugs.

The following will do what you want it to do. Note that the back-end document gets saved before being displayed in the workspace, this is to be able to display the Rich Text Field which is the body of the Mail.

```
Dim oSess As Object
Set oSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Dim ntsServer As String
ntsServer = oSess.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer", True)
Dim ntsMailFile As String
ntsMailFile = oSess.GetEnvironmentString("MailFile", True)

Dim Maildb As Object
Set Maildb = oSess.GetDatabase(ntsServer, ntsMailFile)
If Not Maildb.IsOpen Then
    Maildb.OPENMAIL
End If

Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Form", "Memo")
Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("SendTo", "Joe Example")
Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Subject", "Subject Text")
Set Body = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
Call Body.APPENDTEXT("Body text here")
Call Body.ADDNEWLINE(2)
Call MailDoc.Save(True, True)

Set Workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Call Workspace.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)
```

Comment: Hello @Andrew Magerman, it was complicate to describe my problem. Anyway the answer i was looking for was in a few words : AppActivate "Lotus Notes" :D